# Running Grep command from java

Tags: java, grep

I want to run grep command from java.

Here is what I had tried. Please let me know, why it is not displaying ouput.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "grep 'Report Process started' server.log|wc -l" };
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you wanting to outsource `grep`?

Comment: @chrylis, I want to get the count of 'Report Process started' string in log file... Is there any other way I can get count of that string...suggest

Comment: Right, so why not just count it yourself in Java? Or run everything from a shell script?

Comment: Try supplying the full path to the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pipe grep's output to `wc -l`. Just use `grep -c` like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "grep -c 'Report Process started' /path/to/server.log"};
```

Though I must say that doing this right inside Java is much cleaner. Consider code like this:

```
String logdata = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/server.log")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
final String needle = "Report Process started";
int occurrences = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index < logdata.length() && (index = logdata.indexOf(needle, index)) >= 0) {
    occurrences++;
    index += needle.length();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must check for any errors.

```
private static void printStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "grep 'Report Process started' server.log|wc -l"};
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        printStream(proc.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Error : ");
        printStream(proc.getErrorStream());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```